# Toast, show method not found

Tags: android, widget, toast

also put an import
import android.widget.Toast;

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(VALUE);
Context context = this;
CharSequence text = value;
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
public Toast T = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
T.show(); -  this is red and shows an error? does somebody knows what I did wrong?
```

Comment: move that *stuff* into `onCreate` (or into a method)

Comment: Blackbelt thanks I put it not in the on create place, this fixed it.:)

Answer (score 1):

Change with this:

```
Toast toast = new Toast(context);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setText("");
toast.show();
```

Comment: Thanks Ruben, but it still doesn't understand the methods and marked it as red, I mean the show() and set text().   maybe I'm missing an import or something, or do I need to do something else in order to use this toast class?